# При сборке jar пропадают избражения

Tags: java, gui, gif

IDEA, Java, gui-приложение. Импортировал в проект несколько картинок, отображаемых в приложении.

Лежат по пути *./src/myproject/images/1.gif*

При запуске (Run) в IDEA всё работает, но когда я собираю проект в .jar через Project Structure - artifacts, и запускаю полученный jar файл картинок в приложении нет.
В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: собираете мавеном?

Comment: Попробуйте положить картинки в папку resources, помеченную как ресурсы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все ресурсы приложения хранятся в папке resources, причем проследите что она отличается по цвету от прочих. Проверьте путь указанный в коде. Указывайте только относительные пути.

Comment: Действительно. Указал папку ресурсов как показано тут -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717038/adding-resources-in-intellij-for-java-project , скинул туда сами ресурсы - всё заработало.